# can't find main class in contribution to eclipse development for junit

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pde

I am new to eclipse plugin development and just encounter a strange issue when practicing in the article "Contribution to Eclipse" Chapter 7. The issue says "Can't find the Main class" and then hanging forever when I right click "Run Test" in the example class org.eclipse.contribution.junit.SampleTest. I did check that the class is already there. What I tried to find the problem are,

- I create another hello word plugin project and it can be run successfully. Hence I don't think it is the Eclipse Environment issue like can't locate the main class.
- I debug into the eclipse workbench, and the error occurred when step into class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMRunner below fragment

  IProcess process = DebugPlugin,newProcess(launch, p, renderProcessLabel(cmdLine),
    getDefaultProcessMap());

I am not sure what's going wrong. My develop environment is windows xp sp3, eclipse 2.1 and jre4. I know this environment is too old nowadays, but I'd like to setup it to keep the same as the article to reduce any other impacts.

If you faced this kind of issue or have any solutions, I will not feel alone and will be happy if you can share any ideas...

Comment: Where can we find this article you are following? You are almost certainly better off using at least Java 6 and the current version of Eclipse... and probably finding a new source for your learning material that is more up to date.
Also, can you provide more details about the errors you are seeing? It will be hard for anyone to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thos should work.

```
IProcess process = DebugPlugin, new Process(launch, p, renderProcessLabel(cmdLine), getDefaultProcessMap());
```

Comment: Hi Marko,thanks for your idea, but this is the eclipse jdt source code, my question is why this broken when debug in the eclipse plugin mode...